# jQuery animation with escaped-fragmented URL (hash-bang, #!)

Tags: php, ajax, url, web-crawler, hashbang

My website is setup like: when the page loads, a jQuery animation -- in the template -- is played which, on completion, further makes an Ajax call to fetch the content of the page. Now, I want to deploy hashbang like http://com-address/#!page and I need to retain the animation at the page load as well. But I assume the problem with this setup is; when the web-crawler visits the page, it doesn't wait for the animation to complete and make the Ajax call. It requires the state of the page with the loaded content (which, in my case is acquired after the animation is completed).

Given the above scenario, which way is better:

1. Change the entire flow and load the page content preemptively and hide it
   till the animation is played.
2. Only when the hash-bang or _escaped_fragment is found in the URL:

   a. follow step 1.

   b.  load the page with the content without animation.
3. My assumption about the web-crawler is incorrect & let the
   current flow as it is.

Any heads-up advice?

**EDIT**

@kdzwinel, thanks for the tip about text-browsers!

On the second thought, I'll go with the option 2(a) because when the crawler visits the resource with fragmented URL, it should get the full resultant content on the page. And if the user navigates directly to the fragmented URL, the user-experience with animation would be intact too (by removing the content on the dynamic content fragment between the page load and the animation starts).

Also for all the other scenarios, we would continue the old flow (animate then fetch via Ajax) because we don't want to refresh the page since the user is already visiting the website and trying to navigate smoothly/seamlessly using anchors with fragmented URL (binding their click events to begin animation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web crawlers don't execute javascript ([webmaster guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769) -

> If fancy features such as JavaScript, cookies, session IDs, frames, DHTML, or Flash keep you from seeing all of your site in a text browser, then search engine spiders may have trouble crawling your site.

), if you wan't your content indexed go with option #1. Load the content when page is opened and if browser supports javascript - hide the content and show the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But that really shouldn't be the case with hash-bang because,if the text-browser encounter an anchor tag with href like #!page, it wouldn't navigate to com-address/#!page, rather it will look for the named anchor (!page). Then only way to navigate to the hash-bang is to refresh the page (if you are already on the same page or use javascript to fetch the window.loacation.hash requests via Ajax) Having said that, Google discovered the idea of Making AJAX-driven Applications Crawlable via escaped-fragmented URLs.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. It doesn't change the fact that javascript won't be executed by webcrawler though, so nothing will be indexed on your main page when crawler visits it. I still think that you should go with option #1.

Comment: Check out the edit section in my post & thanks for your help!